# ADF Out of memory exception

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF with a self hosted integrated runtime and I intermittently get this error:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "'Type=System.OutOfMemoryException,Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "CopyDataEtllongtable",
    "details": []
}
```

[image]

The problem is when I check the integrated runtime logs to see where the memory ran out the graphs are not populated.

I need some ideas about how to approach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an Azure or self-hosted integration runtime? If you're using a self-hosted, I would look at the resource usage on the machine that the self-hosted runtime is installed and running on. I've seen this a lot on self-hosted runtimes that are installed on machines undersized to handle the work that the pipeline is pushing down to them.

Comment: Yes its self hosted but there is a substantial amount of memory on the machines. I was hoping the IR software would report the memory analytics back to the Azure portal

Comment: I was having the same issue, what I did is upgrading the ram from 2gb to 4gb and thing worked out for me.